# Convert Image from Db to Bitmap

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap

Currently, I am trying to get my `image` from the database and then convert it to `Bitmap`. I know how to do it in `VB` but in `C#`, I don't really know it.

This is the sample code in `VB`:

```vb
Dim tempimage As Bitmap = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
imagelist(i) = New Image(Of Gray, Byte)(tempimage)
```

The above code is the code I want to convert to `C#`. Thank you

Comment: Have you bytes in `DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value`?

Comment: I am sorry but i dont get it actually

Answer (score 0):

If you have `byte[]` then try this to get image

```
pictureBox1.Image = GetImage((byte[])DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
public static Image GetImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Convert your image to bitmap** just use something like this:

```
Image YourImageFromGridView;
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) YourImageFromGridView;
```

maybe this help!

Comment: how can i do the data grid view??

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand you. @raaj5671

Comment: its ok i have sort it out my ownself

Answer (score 0):

The C# equivalent to your VB code is:

```
Bitmap tempimage = (Bitmap)DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
imagelist[i] = new Image<Gray, byte>(tempimage);
```

I've assumed that DataGridView1 and imagelist are declared as follows in the VB code (converters need to know this):

```
Dim DataGridView1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Dim imagelist() As System.Windows.Forms.ImageList
```